# Measuring a feature's share of a web service's execution time

Tags: statistics, performance-testing, load-testing, percentile

I have a piece of code that includes a specific feature that I can turn on and off. I want to know the execution time of the feature.

I need to measure this externally, i.e. by simply measuring execution time with a load test tool. Assume that I cannot track the feature's execution time internally.

Now, I execute two runs (on/off) and simply assume that the difference between the resulting execution time is my feature's execution time.

I know that it is not entirely correct to do this as I'm looking at two separate runs that may be influenced by networking, programmatic overhead, or the gravitational pull of the moon. Still, I hope I can assume that the result will still be viable if I have a sufficiently large number of requests.

Now for the real question. I do the above using the average response time. Which is not perfect, but more or less ok.
My question is, what if I now use a percentile (say, 95th) instead?
Would my imperfect subtract-A-from-B approach become significantly more imperfect when using percentiles?

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to the [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) as the "average" approach can mask the problem, for example if you have very low response times during the initial phase of the test when the load is low and very high response times during the main phase of test when the load is immense the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) approach will give you okayish values while with the percentiles you will get the information that the response time for 95% of requests was X or higher.

More information: [Understanding Your Reports: Part 3 - Key Statistics Performance Testers Need to Understand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/understanding-your-reports-part-3-key-statistics-performance-testers-need-understand/)

Comment: I'm not sure my intention came across. I agree that percentiles are preferable, for the reasons you outlined, and more. I do want to use percentiles. However, the question I'm looking to answer is whether the fact that I'm comparing two different runs and then subtracting one run's execution time from the other's (to determine the execution time of a specific feature enabled in one of the runs) is viable when using percentiles.